# Why do the author need to use asStateFlow() in Compose?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is a sample code from the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Jc6-INantQ).

I can't understand why the author need to use `asStateFlow()`.

I think the Code B is OK, right?

**Code A**

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _stateFlow= MutableStateFlow("Hello World")
    val stateFlow = _stateFlow.asStateFlow()
    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _stateFlow= MutableStateFlow("Hello World")
    val stateFlow = _stateFlow
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Code A** makes the `stateFlow` *read-only* while **Code B** exposes the *mutable* state flow as is.

The documentation of `asStateFlow()` is pretty clear about this:

> Represents this mutable state flow as a read-only state flow.

If you take a look at the implemenation, you can see that it wraps the current (mutable) flow in a `ReadonlyStateFlow` which is, well, read-only:

```kotlin
public fun <T> MutableStateFlow<T>.asStateFlow(): StateFlow<T> =
    ReadonlyStateFlow(this, null)
```

To make it easier to understand, if you use `MainViewModel` in a component, this outsider will be able to read the values but not write them in case of **Code A**. Meanwhile, if you use **Code B**, the outsider component may emit its own values to the state flow. This is usually undesirable as it should be the `ViewModel`'s responsibility to emit data (this is called *unidirectional data flow*) as a response to actions coming from the observers (the view components).

Comment: Thanks!  But you know that  `stateFlow` is `val` in both Code A and Code B, I don't understand how outsider component may emit its own values to the state flow in Code B, could you give me some sample code?

Comment: `val` means that the field cannot be set to a different value. However, emitting a value is not setting the field to a different value, instead it executes an operation on it (specifically calls the `emit(...)` function). To put it into a real life context: lets say you have a car. If you replace the car, you set the value to the new car, but if you open the door of the car, you call `car.open()`, which will open the current car's door without replacing the car with a new one.

Comment: MutableStateFlow extends StateFlow, so if you specify the type explicitly e.g `val stateFlow:  StateFlow<String>`, you will make it read-only. You create/update a job in ReadonlyStateFlow state using e.g stateIn, but not with asStateFlow, so what benefits is it giving as opposed to specifying the type explicitly?

Comment: @Pitos Explicitly specifying the type will not make it read-only, it merely hides certain functions of the instance. In that case simply casting the `stateFlow` to `MutableStateFlow` would allow one to make it writable again, so this would work in your solution: `(stateflow as MutableStateFlow<String>).emit("hack")`, but would crash with the `asStateFlow()`.