# Can val uiStateA be changed outside ViewModel in Code A?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I know that `asStateFlow()` will represent a mutable state flow as a read-only state flow, so I think the `val uiStateB` can't be changed outside `InterestsViewModel` in Code B, it's a good way.

`val uiStateA` is generated by `combine`, can `val uiStateA` be changed outside `TaskDetailViewModel` in Code A ?  If so, is the Code A good way?

**Code A**

```
class TaskDetailViewModel @Inject constructor(
    ...
) : ViewModel() {
  
    private val _userMessage: MutableStateFlow<Int?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)
    private val _isTaskDeleted = MutableStateFlow(false)
    private val _taskAsync = taskRepository.getTaskStream(taskId)
    
   val uiStateA: StateFlow<TaskDetailUiState> = combine(
       _userMessage, _isLoading, _isTaskDeleted, _taskAsync
    ) { userMessage, isLoading, isTaskDeleted, taskAsync ->
       when (taskAsync) {
          ...
       }
   } .stateIn(
       scope = viewModelScope,
       started = WhileUiSubscribed,
       initialValue = TaskDetailUiState(isLoading = true)
   )
}
```

**Code B**

```
class InterestsViewModel(
    private val interestsRepository: InterestsRepository
) : ViewModel() {
 
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(InterestsUiState(loading = true))
    val uiStateB: StateFlow<InterestsUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does Code A use `stateIn`? There’s too much code removed to see what you’re doing. Using `stateIn` does produce a StateFlow that cannot be cast to MutableStateFlow, if that’s what you’re asking.

Comment: Thanks!  Code A use `stateIn` in my updated code.

Comment: Can `val uiStateA` be changed outside `TaskDetailViewModel` in Code A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stateIn` creates a StateFlow that cannot be cast to MutableStateFlow, just like `asStateFlow()` does. Therefore you cannot change the `value` or what’s being emitted using the `uiStateA` reference. (Except through reflection which can achieve pretty much anything.)

Answer (score 1):

No.  Vals can only be set once, at initialization.  After that, attempting to change them will cause a compile error.  If you want to change it (which I would not recommend, it would be an awkward architecture and open up bugs) you'd use a var instead.

However values can still be emitted to the stateflow.  So if code did uiStateA.value they would get different values as the flows it combines change.

Comment: Thanks! 
The outsider component may not emit its own values to the state flow with Code B.
But I think the outsider component may emit its own values to the state flow with Code A, It's too bad, it's not unidirectional data flow with Code A.

You can see the  related topic  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71276772/why-do-the-author-need-to-use-asstateflow-in-compose